# Using usestate hook with array when getting data from redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, use-state

I'm getting my family from store like below from very top

```
const family:Family = useSelector((state:any) => state.family.family);
```

This is my family object

```
address: "No 48, Katukurunda"
enabled: true
id: 1
members: Array(2)
0: {id: "5", first_name: "Rohan", last_name: "Perera"}
1: {id: "4", first_name: "Sohani", last_name: "Perera"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
monthly_contribution: 50
name: "Mendis Family
```

as you can see clearly members have 2 items

So I have a UseState item to calculate row numbers like this

```
const [rowNumber, setRowNumber] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

I have a useEffect on top to `setRowNumber` like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (family) {
      family.members.forEach(() => {
        setRowNumber([...rowNumber, rowNumber.length + 1]);
      });
    }
  }, [family, setRowNumber]);
```

Just to check how many rows available when page loading I have added this code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(rowNumber);
  }, [rowNumber]);
```

but above console log shows me this `[1]`, an array with only one item.
What happened to the second member ?

I use `rowNumber.map()` to show available members of that `Family`. But when page loads it shows only one text box which is correct according to below `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(rowNumber);
      }, [rowNumber]);
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Why rowNumber has only ONE item ?

`family.members` clearly has 2 items

I just realized only last value contains in `rowNumber` array

Comment: I know that you already found a solution but for me it looks like there is no need to use "state" for `rowNumber`. You can just calculate rowNumber in your function component as it is just derived from your fmaily object. But naturally i can't tell for sure because i don't know your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related to the fact that `setRowNumber` is async. Have you tried to use a local array? Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (family) {
      let result = [];
      family.members.forEach(() => {
        result.push(result.length + 1);
      });
      setRowNumber(result);
    }
  }, [family, setRowNumber]);
```

Comment: Happy to ear that =)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setState()` in React is asynchronous, this means that `setState` does not update state immediately, so in the last iteration it will add `0 + 1` in your state.
try to do it like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (family) {
      const rows = [];
      family.members.forEach((value, i) => {
        rows.push(i + 1);
      });
      setRowNumber(rows);
    }
  }, [family, setRowNumber]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Content inside useEffect is wrong for storing array inside useState.

Use below code,

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (family) {
          family.members.map((item) => {
            setRowNumber(()=> { 
              console.log(item); // verify result with this console log
              return [...rowNumber, rowNumber.length + 1]
             });
          });
        }
      }, [family, setRowNumber]);
```